# PWA with Node.js, Registering Service Worker, Navigator is not defined

Tags: node.js, service-worker, navigator

I am trying to turn my existing Webapp into a PWA. I am using Node.js, the structure of my project was generated with express. The server is currently a https server, but the certificate is not safe yet. I tried to register a serviceWorker in my app.js, but when I run npm start I get the following error:

[image: Console output when trying to start the server]

Here is the code I am using, to register the sw:

```
registerSW();

function registerSW() { 
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
      .then((reg) => {
        console.log('Service worker registered -->', reg);
      }, (err) => {
        console.error('Service worker not registered -->', err);
      });
  }
}
```

I am unsure which information is needed to solve the error. If you need more context I will gladly provide it.

Thank you for your answers!

Carina

Comment: it seems that you are trying to access the Navigator object in a NodeJs environment, correct? Navigator (window.navigator) is available only in a browser env, you should use your `registerSW` function in the JS code that runs in the client, not in the server

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Yes, I am trying to do this on the serverside. I am unsure where to put in on the client side, since I have quite a few JSs there. When exactly should I call it? When making a request to the server?

Comment: Okay, I figured I could put this at the end of my login html file. This seems to work, but I am unsure if this is the right place to put it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, usually you want it to run on each page I suppose, you should add it to a common js file included in all page

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will implement it there!